# AS3 / Flex 4, hide nodes in Tree, while keeping children visible

Tags: flex4, tree, hide, nodes

I'm displaying data from an XML file (simplified below) with an mx:Tree class in Flex.  I don't want the array node to show up, as it distracts from what's important. But I need to retain it for later when I copy the tree.  Can I hide all array nodes while keeping children of array nodes visible?  Thanks.

```
<property name="responses">
    <array>
        <object type="Type 1">
            <property name="text" value="some text"/>
            <property name="next" value="3"/>
        </object>
        <object type="Type 2">
            <property name="text" value="some text"/>
            <property name="next" value="3"/>
        </object>
    </array>
</property>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I extended DefaultDataDescriptor and everything worked.

Answer (score 0):

Create a custom Tree data descriptor.

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/controls/treeClasses/ITreeDataDescriptor.html

Comment: Thanks, that seems like the way to go.  However it doesn't seem to call getChildren in my custom class. The constructor gets called, but getChildren does not.  And I'm definitely providing a getChildren function, or else it wouldn't compile.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Set showRoot on your tree to false. That should take care of it.

Comment: That didn't work. I was implementing iTreeDataDescriptor. Once I extended DefaultDataDescriptor, it worked. Thanks.